# Connecting controller fan on RAMPS 1.4 for Marlin

Tags: marlin, wiring, fans

I have radial fan with 2 pins connector and always kept it connected to `GND`/`5V` pins (marked J5 at the left bottom on pinout image for my controller board).

I've stumbled upon the `USE_CONTROLLER_FAN` feature of Marlin which allows setting some pin to be used for PWM-controlling a control board fan. I think `SERVO0_PIN` should do fine (`D11` at the bottom center on the pinout image), but I'm not sure how to connect it.

1. Should I split connector and use `GND` + `D11` pins?
2. Or should I use some proper PWM fan for that (which are always 4pin and then how would one connect THAT to those pins?)
3. Is it safe to run a fan directly from board pins or should I resort to using either unused MOSFET outputs (e.g. `FAN` MOSFET pin marked as `D9` on the left)?
4. Should I use dedicated MOSFET board to drive that fan using that SERVO0_PIN?

[image: MKS GEN v1.4 board pinout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Servo pins are PWM pins, so yes `D11` can be used, but not directly connected to the fan as the pins only allow a very low current. You'll need a MOSFET to drive the fan. You don't need 4-pin fans, 2-pin fans will suffice.